# In an input text how to set value with an object and display a field of the object?

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I use form reactive and I get an object:

```
{
 id: 47,
 codice: "Milano"
}
```

that send me the server.

When I assign it to the input text it display [object Object].

How to display "Codice" field in the input but mantain the value with the object?
Because when I submitting the form I retrive values with

```
this.editForm.get('destZona').value
```

and I need both information: id and codice.

If you want can I share with StackBlitz an example.
Thanks!

Comment: pls share with StackBlitz

Comment: Can you not use this.editForm.get('id').value ?

Comment: @Hamza ok! I prepare it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create `formGroup` variable

```
myForm: FormGroup;
```

create a method that will take object and turn it into `FormGroup`

```
createFormGroup(obj): FormGroup {
    return new FormGroup({
      id: new FormControl(obj.id),
      codice: new FormControl(obj.codice),
    });
  }
```

While subscribing to service use RxjS `map` to generate FormGroup and assign to  `myForm` variable

```
  constructor(private dataService: DataService) {
    dataService
      .getData()
      .pipe(
        map((data) => (this.myForm = this.createFormGroup(data)))
      )
      .subscribe();
  }
```

In template:

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm">
  <input type="text" formControlName="codice" />
</form>
```

[Angular demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-kdb3qx?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Answer (score 0):

Input text will display and return text, you cannot put objects in it.

You should have a child form group for the destZona object.

```
this.editForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    destZona: this.formBuilder.group({
        id: [yourObjId],
        codice: [yourObjCodice]
    })
});
```

Then you can refer to it in your template with a `formGroupName="destZona"` on one of your input parent, and put `formControlName="codice"` on the input.